# Two proportion sample size calculation

Tags: self-study, sample-size, statistical-power, proportion

**Question**

A drug maker wants to design a study in which two medications are compared. The first group has seen a improvement in 40%. Researchers want to see if the newer drug will improve this by 10% so they design a study. Assuming a study with power of 80% and a two-sided significance level of 5%. How many participants are required to detect a difference of 10% between the two groups.

**My attempt and understanding**

From the information gathered above there are two critical values $Z_{1-\alpha/2} = 1.96$ and $Z_{\beta}=0.84$ given the significance level of $\alpha = 0.05$. From the proportions, $p_{0} = 0.4$ and the proposed new drug should have the second group $p_{1} = 0.5$. The difference $\theta = p_{1}-p_{0} = 0.1$. The hypotheses

\begin{align}
H_{0}:\theta &= 0 \\
H_{1}: \theta &\neq 0
\end{align}

However, I am unsure what formula has been used to calculate this. I have run command in R which has given me $\approx 388$ per group.

```
> power.prop.test(p1 = 0.4, p2 = 0.5, alternative = "two.sided",
+                 sig.level = 0.05,
+                 power = 0.80)

     Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

              n = 387.3385
             p1 = 0.4
             p2 = 0.5
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

However, I am unsure what formula has been used to calculate the sample size. From my understanding this has been a comparison of two binomial proportions. If I could get any assistance in understand how this was calculated, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Minor nitpick in the phrasing of question, there isn't one sample size that lets you detect "a difference of 10%", as that depends on the actual values that differ - this is specifically the number of patients needed to detect the difference between 40% and 50%. Finding the 10% difference between 40% and 50% requires more than five times as many subjects as finding the 10% difference between 0% and 10%!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A formula based on a large sample test for the equality of two independent proportions is:

\begin{align}
n_1 &= \kappa n_2 \\
n_2 &= \frac{(z_{\alpha/2} + z_{\beta})^2}{(p_1 - p_2)^2}\left[\frac{p_1(1 - p_1)}{\kappa} + p_2(1 - p_2)\right]
\end{align}

Where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the proportions, $\kappa$ is the allocation ratio and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the significance level and 1-Power.

**Reference**

Chow S-C, Shao J, Wang H, Lokhnygina Y (2018): Sample size calculations in clinical research. 3rd ed. CRC Press.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't precisely from a formula.  According to the code inside `power.prop.test`, the *power* for any value of `n` is calculated as

```
pnorm((sqrt(n) * abs(p1 - p2) - (qnorm(sig.level/2,lower.tail = FALSE) * 
   sqrt((p1 + p2) * (1 - (p1 + p2)/2))))/
   sqrt(p1 * (1 - p1) + p2 * (1 - p2)))
```

or in traditional notation
$$\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}|p_1-p_2|-z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{(p_1+p_2)(1-(p_1+p_2)/2)}}{\sqrt{p_1(1-p_2)+p_2(1-p_2)}}  \right)  $$
and numerical root-finding methods are used to get the value of `n` that makes this equal to 80%.

That's not necessarily how you'd do the computations by hand.

Comment: That is interesting. How would one go about calculating sample sizes by hand given the context?